# Chart.js error: Bar is not a function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```
        <canvas id="chart" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
        <script>
           var barData = {
           labels : [{% for item in labels %}
                          "{{item}}",
                      {% endfor %}],
           datasets : [
              {
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                 data : [{% for item in values %}
                              {{item}},
                            {% endfor %}]
              }
              ]
           };

           var mychart = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");

           steps = 10;
           max = 10;    
           // draw bar chart
           new Chart(mychart).Bar(barData, {
                scaleOverride: true,
                scaleSteps: steps,
                scaleStepWidth: Math.ceil(max / steps),
                scaleStartValue: 0,
                scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
                scaleShowGridLines : true,
                barShowStroke : true,
                scaleShowLabels: true
           });
        </script>
```

It makes an error:(index):61

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).Bar is not a function
>       at (index):61

I already try chart.js, chart.min.js and Chart.bundle.js, in vain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using old syntax *(used in ChartJS 1.x)* for creating your chart, and you might be using the latest version *(2.7.0)* of ChartJS library.

In latest version of ChartJS, you should create your chart as follows :

```
var mychart = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");

new Chart(mychart, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: [{% for item in labels %}
                    "{{item}}",
               {% endfor %}],
      datasets: [{
         data: [{% for item in values %}
                    {{item}}, 
                {% endfor %}],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
         pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               stepSize: 10
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

Refer to the [official documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html#creating-a-chart) to learn more.